# Wierd maths with skew

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slide show that I need to build. This flash animation is ultimately what I want to achieve: http://ne.matthewjonat.com/assets/NE_Animation.swf

I have started building it using 1px wide divs for the lines. but to give them the skew effect I use the CSS3 -webkit-transform: skew(-15deg) parameter.

Everything will be positioned according to the window size. to create the content block with text I started by dividing the screen into thirds (minus the pixels outside the container div) to use for the width. The height of the content div would be defined by its contents. To set the position...use the maths i did earlier to position it 2 thirds of the screen from the left of the window and also its own height * 2 in pixels from the top.

Because I am using the -webkit-transform: skew(-15deg); the div no longer matches up with the line. I need to work out how many pixels to move the div by so that it matches up with the middle line. Is there a way to work out a divs position on the screen relative to a skewed element?

The code I am using for this is as follows:

although you can see a better version here: http://ne.matthewjonat.com/for-dev

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var $wHeight = $(window).height(),
  $wWidth = $(window).width(),
  hMinusMenu = $wHeight - 77,
  $slideContent = $('.slide-content.one');
 //console.log(hMinusMenu);
 $('.slide-bg, .lines').height(hMinusMenu);
 
 //set width of slide content box
 var slideContentWidth = $wWidth / 3;
 $slideContent.width(slideContentWidth);
 
 //get width of outside container
 var outerWidth = ($wWidth - $('.container').width()) / 2,
  slideTxtTop = (hMinusMenu / 2) - $slideContent.height();
  
 //position lines
 var rightLinePos = $slideContent.outerWidth() + outerWidth;
  bottomLinePos =  $slideContent.outerHeight() + slideTxtTop,
  topLinePos = slideTxtTop - 1;
 $('.lines .right').height(hMinusMenu).css('left', rightLinePos);
 $('.lines .bottom').css('top', bottomLinePos);
 $('.lines .top').css('top', topLinePos);
 $('.lines .left').height(hMinusMenu).css('left', outerWidth);
 
 //position first slide content accordingly
 $slideContent.css('left', rightLinePos).css('top', bottomLinePos + 1);
 
 //position second slide-content
 
 
 //move out right line
 $('.lines .right.move-out-right').css('display','block').css('top',bottomLinePos - 20).animate({
  'left':'+='+slideContentWidth
 },600, function(){
  $('.slide-content.one').fadeIn();
  //setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
 });
 
});
```

```css
.lean-forward{
 -webkit-transform: skew(-15deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-15deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-15deg);
}
.lean-back{
 -webkit-transform: skew(15deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(15deg);
    -o-transform: skew(15deg);
}
.slide-container{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 margin-top:77px;
}
.slide-content{
    padding:20px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
.slide-content .title{
 font-size:30px;
 font-weight:bold;
}
.slide-content .text{
 font-size:18px;
}
.slide-content p{
 color:#FFF;
 -webkit-transform: skew(15deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(15deg);
    -o-transform: skew(15deg);
}
.slide-content.one{
 background-color:rgba(112,1,1,0.5);
}
.slide-content.two{
 background-color:rgba(51,204,153,0.5);
}
.slide-content.three{
 background-color:rgba(196,16,57,0.5);
}

.slide{
 display:none;
}
.slide.active{
 display:block;
}

.lines{
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.lines .right, .lines .left, .lines .top, .lines .bottom{
 position:absolute;
 background-color:#fff;
}
.lines .right, .lines .left{
 width:1px;
}
.lines .top, .lines .bottom{
 height:1px;
 width:100%;
}
.lines .left, .lines .right.move-out-right, .lines .right.move-out-left{
 display:none;
}
.lines .right.move-out-right{
 bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-container">
   <div class="lines">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="right lean-forward"></div>
    <div class="right move-out-right lean-forward"></div>
    <div class="right move-out-left lean-forward"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="left lean-forward"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="slide active slide-bg" style="background-image:url('http://ne.matthewjonat.com/assets/images/slides/1.jpg');">
    <div class="slide-content one lean-forward">
     <p><span class="title">Technically-rigorous*</span><br />
     <span class="text">Building your legacy is priceless, leaving a future for your family is the most important gift you can give.</span></p>
    </div>  
   </div>
   <div class="slide slide-bg" style="background-image:url('assets/images/slides/2.jpg');">
    <div class="slide-content two lean-forward">
     <p><span class="title">Legacy-oriented*</span><br />
     <span class="text">Building your legacy is priceless, leaving a future for your family is the most important gift you can give.</span></p>
    </div>  
   </div>
   <div class="slide slide-bg" style="background-image:url('assets/images/slides/3.jpg');">
    <div class="slide-content three lean-forward">
     <p><span class="title">Creatively-inspired*</span><br />
     <span class="text">Building your legacy is priceless, leaving a future for your family is the most important gift you can give.</span></p>
    </div>  
   </div>
  </div>
```

NOTE: Apologies for the poor post I had previously. I just find this incredibly difficult to explain properly...I hope my second attempt is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rotate the lines, instead of skewing them, and set the appropriate `transform-origin`, your code will work fine as it is. The origin's `y` shoud be the same as the top of the content div.

Just add this to your css:

```
.right.lean-forward {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 361px;    
}

.slide-content.one.lean-forward {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;    
}
```

Demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ja7kfe8k/1/).

Note: The rotated line is not covering the full image height, so you may want to add a `scaleY` transform after the `rotate` to make it longer.

Edit: You can set the transform-origin like this ([new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ja7kfe8k/2/)):

```
$('.lines .right').css('transform-origin', '0 ' + bottomLinePos + 'px');
```

Comment: Where does the 361px come from? Is that just relative to the screen you were looking at at the time? I need to be able to set the value dynamically with jQuery preferably...thanks for the answer so far though! deffo something for me to think about!u Hadnt considered rotate instead of skew.